# QStyledItemDelegate and QStandardItem preventing change text , enable only select and copy

Tags: c++, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a simple QStandardItem and QTableView and QStyledItemDelegate. They have delegates , I would like to disable the possibility for user to change the content of a column in the table, and allow only select and copy. I guess it related to `QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor`.

When I set it to return 0, it just disable everything.

```
QWidget *InfoTableItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                                    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
    return 0;
}
```

my question is , how can i defined it so i can only select and copy , and disable the option to edit it like delete or change the text

Comment: 1) Don't forget to write your question... 2) What is "disable everything"? 3) Returning 0 should be ok here, it doesn't create editor widget so you cannot edit the model.

Comment: thanks , all i want to be able to select and copy the text , but not edit it ( delete or change ) when i do this with return 0, i can't select and copy it

Answer (score 1):

If your data can be showed as simple text, then you can return a QLineEdit in [read-only mode](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlineedit.html#readOnly-prop). If you have images or other types of data, maybe a selectable QLabel with some html in it (to make a QLabel selectable, you have to include `Qt::TextSelectableByMouse` or `Qt::TextSelectableByKeyboard` in the [label's interaction flags](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlabel.html#textInteractionFlags-prop)).

Comment: 1/ That's not a very constructive comment. 2/ Why do you think it's not a good way to do this ? 3/ You cannot select directly, it is not implemented in Qt. The other way is to write a delegate that keeps track of the mouse and paint the widget accordingly, which is much more work I think.

Comment: sorry for the comment . but i guess by now if i use delegate for the table i can do it with setting flags